# Why is Entity Framework (with RIA Services) excluding parent records when child records don't exist?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, wcf-ria-services

Entity Framework 4 is excluding records that I don't believe it should be.  Here is my scenario:

Table Definitions

```
Table_1

    UniqueIdentifier ID not null
    int AnotherField

Table_2

    UniqueIdentifier ID not null
    UniqueIdentifier Table_1ID not null
    int Priority not null
```

There is a relationship between table 1 and table 2 through the table_1ID field.  It's defined in the database and the entity framework recognizes it.

I have a Query defined in my DomainService as:

```
private ObjectQuery<Table_1> Table_1WithIncludes()    
{        
    return this.ObjectContext.Table_1        
        .Include("Table_2")                
}
```

If I have a record in table 1 and table 2 that are related, they get returned as expected.  If I do NOT have a record in table 2 that relates back to table 1, then the record is getting excluded.

Upon running SQL Server Profiler, I noticed that the entity framework added the following CAST and where clauses:

```
CASE WHEN ([Join2].[Priority] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]

WHERE ([Project1].[C1] > 0)
```

So essentially, if the Priority field in Table_2 is null (which it is when there isn't a record in Table 2 that corresponds to the parent Tabe_1 table) the where clause causes both records to drop out (null > 0 fails).

Now, if I change the definition of the Priority field so that it is not required, it eliminates the cast and the check and all is well.   But it doesn't seem like I should have to do this.

**Have I done something wrong?  Is my understanding faulty?**

The full EntityQuery and generated query text is below in case it is helpful.

```
    private ObjectQuery<Event> EventsWithIncludes()
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.Events
            .Include("Place")
            .Include("EventInvitees")
            .Include("EventInvitees.User");
    }


exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Project2].[NumberOfPeople] AS [NumberOfPeople], 
[Project2].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Project2].[CreatorID] AS [CreatorID], 
[Project2].[CreateDate] AS [CreateDate], 
[Project2].[PlacesID] AS [PlacesID], 
[Project2].[EventDate] AS [EventDate], 
[Project2].[EventTime] AS [EventTime], 
[Project2].[Availability] AS [Availability], 
[Project2].[EscalationLevels] AS [EscalationLevels], 
[Project2].[Rank] AS [Rank], 
[Project2].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion], 
[Project2].[ID1] AS [ID1], 
[Project2].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Project2].[Phone] AS [Phone], 
[Project2].[DefaultPar] AS [DefaultPar], 
[Project2].[DefaultSlope] AS [DefaultSlope], 
[Project2].[DefaultRating] AS [DefaultRating], 
[Project2].[CreateDate1] AS [CreateDate1], 
[Project2].[UpdateDate] AS [UpdateDate], 
[Project2].[MetroAreaID] AS [MetroAreaID], 
[Project2].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project2].[PriorityOrder] AS [PriorityOrder], 
[Project2].[ID2] AS [ID2], 
[Project2].[EventsID] AS [EventsID], 
[Project2].[InviteeUsersID] AS [InviteeUsersID], 
[Project2].[RowVersion1] AS [RowVersion1], 
[Project2].[Attending] AS [Attending], 
[Project2].[StatusChange] AS [StatusChange], 
[Project2].[ID3] AS [ID3], 
[Project2].[First] AS [First], 
[Project2].[Last] AS [Last], 
[Project2].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
[Project2].[Password] AS [Password], 
[Project2].[Gender] AS [Gender], 
[Project2].[Email] AS [Email], 
[Project2].[Email_Sharing] AS [Email_Sharing], 
[Project2].[Email_Receive] AS [Email_Receive], 
[Project2].[Phone1] AS [Phone1], 
[Project2].[Phone_Sharing] AS [Phone_Sharing], 
[Project2].[Phone_Receive] AS [Phone_Receive], 
[Project2].[CreateDate2] AS [CreateDate2], 
[Project2].[UpdateDate1] AS [UpdateDate1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Project1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Project1].[CreatorID] AS [CreatorID], 
    [Project1].[CreateDate] AS [CreateDate], 
    [Project1].[NumberOfPeople] AS [NumberOfPeople], 
    [Project1].[PlacesID] AS [PlacesID], 
    [Project1].[EventDate] AS [EventDate], 
    [Project1].[Availability] AS [Availability], 
    [Project1].[EscalationLevels] AS [EscalationLevels], 
    [Project1].[Rank] AS [Rank], 
    [Project1].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion], 
    [Project1].[EventTime] AS [EventTime], 
    [Extent3].[ID] AS [ID1], 
    [Extent3].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent3].[Phone] AS [Phone], 
    [Extent3].[DefaultPar] AS [DefaultPar], 
    [Extent3].[DefaultSlope] AS [DefaultSlope], 
    [Extent3].[DefaultRating] AS [DefaultRating], 
    [Extent3].[CreateDate] AS [CreateDate1], 
    [Extent3].[UpdateDate] AS [UpdateDate], 
    [Extent3].[MetroAreaID] AS [MetroAreaID], 
    [Join2].[ID1] AS [ID2], 
    [Join2].[EventsID] AS [EventsID], 
    [Join2].[InviteeUsersID] AS [InviteeUsersID], 
    [Join2].[PriorityOrder] AS [PriorityOrder], 
    [Join2].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion1], 
    [Join2].[Attending] AS [Attending], 
    [Join2].[StatusChange] AS [StatusChange], 
    [Join2].[ID2] AS [ID3], 
    [Join2].[First] AS [First], 
    [Join2].[Last] AS [Last], 
    [Join2].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
    [Join2].[Password] AS [Password], 
    [Join2].[Gender] AS [Gender], 
    [Join2].[Email] AS [Email], 
    [Join2].[Email_Sharing] AS [Email_Sharing], 
    [Join2].[Email_Receive] AS [Email_Receive], 
    [Join2].[Phone] AS [Phone1], 
    [Join2].[Phone_Sharing] AS [Phone_Sharing], 
    [Join2].[Phone_Receive] AS [Phone_Receive], 
    [Join2].[CreateDate] AS [CreateDate2], 
    [Join2].[UpdateDate] AS [UpdateDate1], 
    CASE WHEN ([Join2].[PriorityOrder] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
    FROM    (SELECT 
        [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
        [Extent1].[CreatorID] AS [CreatorID], 
        [Extent1].[CreateDate] AS [CreateDate], 
        [Extent1].[NumberOfPeople] AS [NumberOfPeople], 
        [Extent1].[PlacesID] AS [PlacesID], 
        [Extent1].[EventDate] AS [EventDate], 
        [Extent1].[Availability] AS [Availability], 
        [Extent1].[EscalationLevels] AS [EscalationLevels], 
        [Extent1].[Rank] AS [Rank], 
    [Extent1].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion], 
    [Extent1].[EventTime] AS [EventTime], 
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[EventInvitees] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[ID] = [Extent2].[EventsID]) AND ([Extent2].[InviteeUsersID] = @p__linq__2)) AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[Events] AS [Extent1] ) AS [Project1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Places] AS [Extent3] ON [Project1].[PlacesID] = [Extent3].[ID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent4].[ID] AS [ID1], [Extent4].[EventsID] AS [EventsID], [Extent4].[InviteeUsersID] AS [InviteeUsersID], [Extent4].[PriorityOrder] AS [PriorityOrder], [Extent4].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion], [Extent4].[Attending] AS [Attending], [Extent4].[StatusChange] AS [StatusChange], [Extent5].[ID] AS [ID2], [Extent5].[First] AS [First], [Extent5].[Last] AS [Last], [Extent5].[UserName] AS [UserName], [Extent5].[Password] AS [Password], [Extent5].[Gender] AS [Gender], [Extent5].[Email] AS [Email], [Extent5].[Email_Sharing] AS [Email_Sharing], [Extent5].[Email_Receive] AS [Email_Receive], [Extent5].[Phone] AS [Phone], [Extent5].[Phone_Sharing] AS [Phone_Sharing], [Extent5].[Phone_Receive] AS [Phone_Receive], [Extent5].[CreateDate] AS [CreateDate], [Extent5].[UpdateDate] AS [UpdateDate]
    FROM  [dbo].[EventInvitees] AS [Extent4]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent4].[InviteeUsersID] = [Extent5].[ID] ) AS [Join2] ON [Project1].[ID] = [Join2].[EventsID]
WHERE ([Project1].[C1] > 0) AND ([Project1].[CreatorID] = @p__linq__0) AND (([Project1].[EventDate] IS NULL) OR ([Project1].[EventDate] >= @p__linq__1))
)  AS [Project2]
ORDER BY [Project2].[ID] ASC, [Project2].[ID1] ASC, [Project2].[C1] ASC',N'@p__linq__2     uniqueidentifier,@p__linq__0 uniqueidentifier,@p__linq__1 datetime2(7)',@p__linq__2='33BB8199-7B25-4B3A-B96D-044EB7DB70AE',@p__linq__0='33BB8199-7B25-4B3A-B96D-044EB7DB70AE',@p__linq__1='1900-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Table Definition

```
USE [TheGreen18]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[EventInvitees]    Script Date: 03/17/2012 22:27:16 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EventInvitees](
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [EventsID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [InviteeUsersID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [PriorityOrder] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RowVersion] [timestamp] NULL,
    [Attending] [bit] NULL,
    [StatusChange] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_EventInvitees] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EventInvitees]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_EventInvitees_Events] FOREIGN KEY([EventsID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Events] ([ID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EventInvitees] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_EventInvitees_Events]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EventInvitees]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_EventInvitees_Users] FOREIGN KEY([InviteeUsersID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EventInvitees] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_EventInvitees_Users]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

If your foreign key is non null able, then your relation is one to many according to EF, some every child must have parent. So theoretically you can not have child without parent.

If you want to have child without parent, then your relation is zero or one to many, and your foreign key should be null able.

Comment: Is this really the way entity framework works?  In nearly all professional work I have done, there have always been situations where you have a parent record (like demographics) with no child records (like address).  I find it hard to believe that in order to account for this situation, the entity framework would require us to allow nulls in a foreign key that should always be provided.  This hurts my core if that type of violation is expected.  Are you sure this is correct?  Have you seen documentation somewhere?

Comment: You can have parent without child, but you can not have child without parent.

Answer (score 0):

What I've seen of Entity Framework a single `Include` is always translated as an outer join. With multiple Includes, however, the order of the includes determines whether the joins are inner or outer.

In your example I assume that "Place" is outer joined, whereas both "EventInvitees" and "User" are inner joined. (At least that's what happens when I do a similar query).

If you would change the order into

```
.Include("EventInvitees")
.Include("EventInvitees.User")
.Include("Place")
```

"Place" would be inner joined and "EventInvitees" outer joined (again, based on my similar case).

I cannot find any documentation on the exact logic of this at MSDN, so your result may differ from mine.

Comment: no....actually if you scroll down in the first large code block you can see that all tables are outer joined (with the exception of the user table which isn't specifically included but is done so using the attributes on the entity model).  I tried reversing the order, but it didn't help.  The same filter is added.

Comment: Ah, yes, overlooked that one. It's a bit frustrating that we seem to be left with trial & error here.

Comment: Yeah...I can get around it, but to do so I have to violate the implementation of the business rule that says priority is required.  I can enforce on the client side but that gets messy.  Just looking for a better way.  Thanks for you looking at it though.

Comment: You may have more success with manually writing joins in linq, Join for inner joins and GroupJoin for outer joins. I think EF will not add its own logic to those.